# Resource files generated by Maven plugin not readable from OSGi bundle

Tags: maven, resources, osgi-bundle, camel-blueprint

In my maven OSGi project, I use the `maven-bundle-plugin` to create my bundle jar.

The `git-commit-id-maven-plugin` generates to *target/git.properties* by default, and they recommend to generate to */target/classes/git.properties* to ensure that the file gets added to the */classes* directory inside the jar:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/../.git</dotGitDirectory>
        <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
        <generateGitPropertiesFilename>
            ${project.build.outputDirectory}/classes/git.properties
        </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
        <includeOnlyProperties>
            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.build.(time|version)$</includeOnlyProperty>
            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id.(abbrev|full)$</includeOnlyProperty>
        </includeOnlyProperties>
        <commitIdGenerationMode>full</commitIdGenerationMode>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That works, the file is present in the resulting jar, but I am unable to read the file from within my OSGi bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the classloader cannot find the resource file at runtime, although it is contained in the bundle, is that the resource file is not declared in *META-INF/MANIFEST.MF*.

Normally, the `maven-bundle-plugin` automatically adds everything inside *src/main/resources* to the manifest. This is why the plugin ignores  *target/classes/git.properties* - the `maven-bundle-plugin` ignores that location.

You can add additional resources to the manifest using an `<Include-Resource/>` instruction in the configuration of the `maven-bundle-plugin`. Note, however:

> By default the bundle plugin converts the project’s Maven resource
> directories into a single  instruction. If you
> specify your own  instruction, this will replace the
> generated one. To include the generated list of Maven resources in
> your own  instruction just add {maven-resources} to
> the list and it will be expanded automatically.

-- [Felix Bundle Plugin Documentation](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#_include_resource)

In my case I wanted my resource to be detected by the `maven-bundle-plugin` automatically, so I decided to have the `git-commit-id-plugin` generate its output to *target/generated-resources/git.properties*:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/../.git</dotGitDirectory>
        <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
        <generateGitPropertiesFilename>
            ${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/git.properties
        </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
        <includeOnlyProperties>
            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.build.(time|version)$</includeOnlyProperty>
            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id.(abbrev|full)$</includeOnlyProperty>
        </includeOnlyProperties>
        <commitIdGenerationMode>full</commitIdGenerationMode>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Next, I added the *target/generated-resources* folder to the Maven reactor using the `build-helper-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-resource</id>
            <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-resource</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In any case, what you need to achieve is that the resource is present in *META_INF/MANIFEST.MF*, like so:

```
Include-Resource: ...all the rest of your resources...,git.propertie
 s=target/generated-resources/git.properties
```

Only then code like the following will work:

```
URL gitPropertiesFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/git.properties");
        String gitInfo;
        if (gitPropertiesFile != null) {
            gitInfo = IOUtils.toString(gitPropertiesFile, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        } else {
            gitInfo = "No version information found";
        }
```

As a sidenote, in case you want to use the excellent `git-commit-id-maven-plugin`: the example above is for V.4.0.0 of that plugin, which works up to Java 8. There are more recent versions, but those have different Maven coordinates. For details, refer to the plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/).